Group lists using DOM manipulation
I'm trying to organize market lists by metro regions but I'm running into issues retrieving elements by their ID. Specifically, I'm encountering a TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'closest').
Here’s my current JavaScript code. I’ve started mapping market IDs to their corresponding metro regions. Next, I’m working on creating the elements and structuring them with their respective <div> wrappers.


const mapping = {
  'Austin': {
    ids: ['91352212', '87371946'],
    description: 'austin lists'
  },
  'Dallas': {
    ids: ['57955430', '19944090'],
    description: 'dallas lists'
  },
  'Houston': {
    ids: ['19944180', '19944174'],
    description: 'houston lists'
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const buildDescription = function(text) {
    el = document.createElement('p');
    el.classList.add('group__description');
    el.innerText = text;
    return el;
  }

  const buildWrapper = function(descriptionEl) {
    el = document.createElement('div')
    el.classList.add('group__contents')
    if (descriptionEl) {
      el.append(descriptionEl);
    }
    return el;
  }

  const buildHeader = function(label) {
    el = document.createElement('h3')
    el.classList.add('group__header')
    el.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
    el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var state = (e.target.getAttribute('aria-expanded') == 'false') ? 'true' : 'false';
      e.target.setAttribute('aria-expanded', state);
      console.log("group expanded");
    })
    el.innerText = label;
    return el;
  }

  const buildGroupWrapper = function(headerEl, wrapperEl) {
    el = document.createElement('div')
    el.classList.add('group')
    el.append(headerEl);
    el.append(wrapperEl);
    return el;
  }

  const rootEl = document.querySelector('div.subscribe-options');

  const buildGroups = function(key, ids, descriptionText) {
    const groupId = key.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', '-');

    description = !!descriptionText ? buildDescription(descriptionText) : undefined;
    wrapper = buildWrapper(description);
    header = buildHeader(key);
    groupWrapper = buildGroupWrapper(header, wrapper);
    rootEl.before(groupWrapper);

    ids.forEach(function(id) {
      const inputEl = document.getElementById('id_' + id);
      const itemEl = inputEl.closest('.item');

      itemEl.setAttribute('data-subscription-id', id);
      itemEl.setAttribute('data-subscription-group', key);
      wrapper.append(itemEl);
    });
    
    if(wrapper.querySelector('.highlighted-subscription')) {
      header.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
    } 
  };

  Object.keys(mapping).forEach(function(key) {
    buildGroups(key, mapping[key].ids, mapping[key].description)
  });

  const miscWrapper = buildWrapper('')
  const miscHeader = buildHeader('Other Marketing')
  const miscGroupWrapper = buildGroupWrapper(miscHeader, miscWrapper);
  rootEl.before(miscGroupWrapper);

  document.querySelectorAll('div.item:not([data-subscription-group])').forEach(function(el) {
    miscWrapper.append(el)
  });
});
.item .item-inner > p {
  display: none;
}

.group__header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #aeaeae;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color:#3e3e3e!important;
}

.group__header[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
  content: '–';
}

.group__header[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
  content: '+';
}

.group__header[aria-expanded="false"] + .group__contents {
  display: none;
}
<div class="item">  
  <div class="item-inner selected">
    <div class="checkbox-row">
      <span class="fakelabel">
        <input id="id_91352212" type="checkbox" checked="" name="id_91352212">
        <span>Central Austin</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">  
  <div class="item-inner selected">
    <div class="checkbox-row">
      <span class="fakelabel">
        <input id="id_57955430" type="checkbox" checked="" name="id_57955430">
        <span>Frisco</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">  
  <div class="item-inner selected">
    <div class="checkbox-row">
      <span class="fakelabel">
        <input id="id_19944180" type="checkbox" checked="" name="id_19944180">
        <span>The Woodlands</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="subscribe-options" style="margin-right: 0">
    <p class="header">Or check here to never receive any emails:</p>
    <p>
        <label for="globalunsub">
            <input name="globalunsub" id="globalunsub" type="checkbox">
            <span>
                Unsubscribe me from all mailing lists.
            </span>
        </label>
    </p>
</div>



HTML should look like this:
<div class="group">
    <h3 class="group__header" aria-expanded="false">Austin</h3>
    <div class="group__contents">
        <p class="group__description">Subscribe to find out everything you need to know about your community in a 5-minute read.</p>
        <div class="item">  
            <div class="item-inner selected">
                <div class="checkbox-row">
                    <span class="fakelabel">
                        <input id="id_91352212" type="checkbox" checked="" name="id_91352212">
                        <span>Central Austin</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Post code as a [mcve] (hint: click the brackets button <>). Minimal is the the optimal word -- there's way too much. Moreover, you should include what the HTML should look like.

Your snippet gets an error on rootEl.before(miscGroupWrapper); because there's no div.subscribe-options.

Your original error is presumably due to const inputEl = document.getElementById('id_' + id); not finding the element. So investigate why the ids list contains incorrect values.

Post has been updated. Thanks for the suggestions.

What should happen if one of the 6 ids in your mapping object isn't found in your html, which only has 3 items with id="id_{id}"?
